# Synchronizing clients

Tags: architecture, networking, client-server, synchronization, time

I have a server-client setup where each client has a number of screens attached, and the screens together form the display. As such, the visuals displayed by each client needs to be roughly in sync. Luckily the domain is not high speed, so I don't have to have them all perfectly in sync, but obviously more in sync is better.

The physical network: About 10 clients need to be synced together. All clients that need to be synced are on the same gigabit LAN, latency is sub 1ms.

The network protocol: Clients are running 100ms behind real time (so there is a 100ms buffer for the server to send out updates).

The digital environment: Realistic environments moving at generally a slow speed (think rate of turn in the order of 10 degrees/minute generally, however it's possible to increase up to maybe 720 in extreme circumstances).

Requirements: There should be as little visible lag between clients as possible.

Requirements for answers: A concept is enough, pointing out the limitations or advantages to different methods would be appreciated. It would be great if it's something you've tried and had failures or successes with in the past, but spit-balling is ok too.

What a good answer would look like: "Using NTP is fine up to X ms or syncing Y clients, but if you need more accuracy than that you should look into doing Z". It doesn't need to be crazy in depth!

Comment: When you implement the simple solution (1) of each client synchronizing with a time server, do you get results that are adequate for your needs?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115328/discussion-on-question-by-user-024673-synchronizing-clients).

Comment: [Consulting the links in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/184121/39518), the system time in Windows for example can be synchronized to within 50 or even 1ms depending on your network setup — but this again is a detail of your specific installation that is in your hands to test but we can only guess about. This is why these quick tests are so important to understand the details of the problem space you're working within.

Comment: @DMGregory The expected de-sync artifacts would be tearing (lines across the screen not lining up). The visuals are realistic landscapes. The domain is not high speed such as an FPS. How do I translate that into a ms timing that could be assessed as acceptable? In my opinion that is an impossible step, which is why I am struggling to find this line of inquiry useful. I feel like a more useful approach would be to suggest solutions and give their expected performance. Eg "NTP is fine to 500ms" or whatever.

Comment: @DMGregory If you tell me what kind of solutions you are thinking about and how they perform then I can try to assess them. I strongly feel that would be a more productive avenue than trying to figure out how many MS would be acceptable through guesswork, and THEN discussing solutions and their performance in the end anyway.

Comment: Perfect. That's the kind of detail we need in your question, so edit it to be sure it states that clearly up-front. You can play to find the amount of desync you can tolerate by just getting a 60 fps video file of similar content as your app and playing it on two side-by-side devices. As for figures for NTP timing, you can find that through a web search — you can see I already provided you with three such values in the link above, but as I keep reminding you, this depends on your network configuration, which is why a test will tell us so much more about what will/won't work in your context.

Comment: @DMGregory It's hard to write a question without knowing what to include, I will edit in the details. Unfortunately there's a bit more nuance but a video might be an ok test. If you let me know what details would help you arrive and an answer then I can try to give you information. If you have 5 potential solutions then just a few lines would be plenty to help me research. Just let me know!

Comment: If you want to create a video wall (a large display from many smaller ones), then you should know that many graphic cards can do that out-of-the-box. They are usually limited to 3-6 displays, but there is some [specialized hardware](https://www.matrox.com/en/video/products/video-walls/7-tip-guide-to-easy-video-wall-designs) which can do many more. Could it be a better solution to have just one client and connect multiple monitors to it?

Comment: @Philipp That would eliminate a lot of headaches, however we require 30+ monitors and they are driven by quite beefy hardware so one machine is unfortunately not an option.  Definitely a good suggestion though if less monitors were needed, this question could well be an XY problem :)