# What are the disadvantages of client-side prediction?

Tags: multiplayer, movement, client-server

There's lots of talk of *server-side* prediction, but I haven't seen a *client-side* alternative implemented anywhere.

My game uses mouse-based movement, so it's easy to predict the player's location 150ms from when the event is sent. Wouldn't this be more accurate than using old data on a receiving client's side?

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this approach that I'm missing? I'm thinking of implementing it, but the lack of existing info gives me cold feet.

Comment: It's probably more that it's pretty straight-forward to determine where everyone will be in a short period of time, when you know everyone's destinations.  Not sure how much discussion one can make out of it.  :)  You'll see a lot more work being done on the fine points of dead reckoning, where the clients don't actually know where exactly other networked players are going, because that's a much trickier problem to solve.

Comment: There was actually some talk about this not so long ago here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31288/how-to-synchronise-the-acceleration-velocity-and-position-of-the-monsters-on-th/31290#31290

Comment: Here's [a more general question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22444/how-does-client-side-prediction-work?rq=1) on the same topic -- just to demonstrate this *has* been done / thought about.